# navigation.goBack() not behaving as expected React Native

Tags: react-native

I have 4 screens in my Signup Component: Scrn 1 --> Scrn 2 --> Scrn 3 --> Scrn 4.
I have placed "Next" at every Screen and "Back" buttons at Screens 2, 3 and 4.

I fill some information in Scrn 1 and navigate to Scrn 2. If I press back now, I land at Scrn 1. BUT NOW if I press "Next", I'm redirected to Scrn 3 instead of Scrn 2.

If I press "Back" now, I'm redirected to Scrn 1 AGAIN and pressing "Next" takes me to Scrn 3 instead of Scrn 2.
Pressing "Back" again causes the same process and I reach Scrn 4.

This bug occurs at any screen I press "Back".

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
  <Button title='Back' type='solid' containerStyle={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
  <Button title="Save and Next" type='solid' containerStyle={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={handleNavigation} />
</View>
```

handleNavigation() takes care of screen names and has Actions to my context.

```
handleNavigation = () => {
  sendScrn1Details(
     username,
     password
  )
  navigation.navigate('Scrn2')
}
```

Every Screen has its own handleNavigation with the same template i.e. Action and navigation.

Is this the expected behaviour? How can I avoid this? This happens to other components as well.

Comment: use ```pop``` instead of ```goBack``` and see what's happen.

Comment: what handleNavigation() do, need more code

Comment: @RedwanAbbs Just `navigation.navigate(screenName);`

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi It's still the same if I use `pop`.

Comment: show us your handleNavigation function.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi I've updated the question to show the handleNavigation function.

Comment: And show us ```sendScrn1Details``` :))

Comment: if you need pass params to screen, you have to send them in navigate function as second arg, or use ```screenProps``` if you need them in all screens, or use context API or Redux.